# how to display an animation from a JSON file in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I tried Image.asset([link][1]). but i am unable to load json animation in Image.asset() widget

Comment: add the contents of the json file and code that you tried so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [Lottie](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie) package available at a pub.dev

Answer (score 0):

By using [converter](https://isotropic.co/tool/video-to-lottie/) you can get your lottie json.

And in flutter add this [lottie](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie) in your project and that gif which you get the json from above link then paste in `assets` folder and the access it like

```
Lottie.asset('assets/gif.json'),
```

Comment: Thank you. Can we change the color of gif in lottie ?